# Executing JavaScript Function When Scrolling in Overflow DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jquery and have been searching many ways to make this script works. Finally, I look it out and tried this script for my index.html

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:300px">
<div style="background-color:black; height:500px">
</div>
</div>
```

My simple JavaScript

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(document).height()==$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()){
       alert('I am at the bottom');
       // Here goes your code.
   }
 });
});
```

Result :

http://jsfiddle.net/agnanzakariya/xGV8Q/53/

Actually, this method is works, but works when browser dimension shrink. I want it works in specific overflow DIV dimension, when user scroll near to bottom, script can execute function.

My reference also this :

http://jsfiddle.net/agnanzakariya/n4pdx/662/

But still, works when browser dimension shrink too.

Comment: Can help you this https://forums.asp.net/t/1971576.aspx?How+Do+You+Detect+If+A+User+Has+Scrolled+To+Bottom+Of+iFrame+

Comment: @b2ok thanks for your help, I solve this problem my self after read your link.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I did it, it's simple thing by the way...

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).height()==$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()){
   alert('I am at the bottom');
   // Here goes your code.
}
});
});
```

To be honest, it distracting little a bit. When

```
$(window).scroll(function()
```

It's global who present entire dimension browser, when you want in specific DIV, in my case in overflow DIV, instead (window) with your (div_id) in script

```
$(divload).scroll(function()
```

And final html code is

```
<div id="divload" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:300px">
<div style="background-color:black; height:500px">
</div>
</div>
```